# ArcMap Layout Templates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layouts, template

I am designing a number of maps for a report and I was wondering is there a location where I can download different layout templates as the default ones in arcmap don't suit what I'm looking for?

Comment: Might be easiest for you to design your own. Doesn't  take much  effort.

Comment: Thanks would arcmap be the best software to do this on or do you know a better opensource that is more suited to displaying?

Comment: if you want to make ArcMap templates, then yes ArcMap is the best software to make it in

Comment: You should be making any templates you use in ArcMap. However, it's a good idea to find similar maps you can reference while making your maps.